# I need to merge data from one table to another, but I have one value that comes from a different table

Tags: sql-server

This is my code

```
MERGE OrderDetailsStructure AS Target
USING SalesOrderData AS Source
ON Source.WebOrderNo=Target.WebOrderNo
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
THEN
INSERT (WebOrderNo,OrderNo,ListTotal,
quantity,ExtendedPrice,[LineNo],Category,SSD,LorH,WorB,Species,FinishingOption,
Sheen,FinishingBrand,StockPaint,SSThick,BRD,TRD,CRD,CRD2,CRD3,CRP1,CRP2,CRP3,Section1,Section2,Section3,Section4,
RailConfig,PanelType,ItemText6,ShutterComments,LouverDirection)

VALUES (Source.WebOrderNo,Source.ListTotal,
Source.quantity,Source.ExtendedPrice,Source.[LineNo],Source.Category,Source.SSD,Source.LorH,Source.WorB,Source.Species,Source.FinishingOption,
Source.Sheen,Source.ColorName,Source.ColorNameStock,Source.[SS Thickness],Source.BRD,Source.TRD,Source.CRD,Source.CRD2,Source.CRD3,Source.CRP1,Source.CRP2,Source.CRP3,Source.Section1,Source.Section2,Source.Section3,Source.Section4,
Source.RailConfig,Source.PanelType,Source.LouverType,Source.Comments,Source.LouverDirection);
```

However, the second value after my insert statement, "OrderNo", will come from a third table. The third table also has the value WebOrderNo. How do I accomplish this?

*********Updated****

So basically I need to merge the data from SalesOrderData(TableA) into OrderDetails (TableB) where it doesn't exist in TableB.

However, the field "OrderNo" is not in TableA. I cannot perform the merge without the "OrderNo" field because in TableB, "OrderNo" is the primary key.

So I have TableC that does contain the field "OrderNo" and the data from TableA has already been merged into TableC.

I can join on the field "WebOrderNo" from TableA to TableC.

Comment: Please see how to provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: `JOIN` to a subquery, with all the columns you need, not a table.

Comment: @larnu I am new to sql. How would the join to a subquery look?

Comment: `USING (SELECT {Column} FROM dbo.FirstTable JOIN dbo.SecondTable ON {JOIN Clause}) ON {Outer Join Clause}` There is an [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#b-using-merge-to-do-update-and-delete-operations-on-a-table-in-a-single-statement) in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql)

Comment: When I try this, I get the error "Ambiguous colummn name 'WebOrderNo'. Is this because I am joining all three table on WebOrderNo?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have updated my description. Hope this clarifies the problem better

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work using an Inner Join. Here is my code

```
INSERT INTO TableB
   (Column1,Column2,....)

SELECT TableC.Column1, TableA.Column2,TableA.Column3....)

FROM TableA INNER JOIN
TableC ON TableA.LikeColumn = TableC.LikeColumn
```